# SQL to LiNQ, left join with condition on join

Tags: sql, linq

I have problem to translate SQL to LINQ. The problem is the condtion on the left join. I can't fit that in to LINQ.

I have tried this. But it's not correct. I need *!u.Inactive* on the left join.

```
from p in db.Persons
join u in db.Users on p.Id equals u.Pid into x
from u in x.DefaultIfEmpty()
where p.Cid == cid && !p.Deleted && !u.Inactive
orderby p.Name ascending
```

SQL:

```
SELECT P.ID, P.Name P.EmpNo, U.ID, U.Class, P.Phone, P.Email 
FROM Persons AS P 
LEFT JOIN Users AS U ON P.ID = U.PID AND U.Inactive <> 1
WHERE P.CID = 1234 AND P.Deleted <> 1
ORDER BY P.Name
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try :

```
from p in db.Persons
join u in db.Users.Where(user => !user.Inactive) on p.Id equals u.Pid into x
from u in x.DefaultIfEmpty()
where p.Cid == cid && !p.Deleted 
orderby p.Name ascending
```

Comment: I don't think `!user.Inactive` is the same as `U.Inactive <> 1` same with deleted.  For example consider in Inactive = 7

Comment: @Hogan as the question is stated I have inferred that inactive was a boolean value.

Comment: @Hogan SQL usually defines the BIT datatype, which is an integer constrained to be 1 or 0. LINQ to SQL translates this to a boolean. It's a good bet that this is what OP is dealing with.

Comment: @RossPresser -- very unlikely, much more common to only use values of 0 and 1 in a field defined as integer.  Bit is not standard SQL.

Comment: @Hogan Yeah, I'm going to need some references to believe your assertion of "very unlikely". I've been dealing with SQL for about two decades and with LINQ for about one. `BIT` to `boolean` is *extremely* common in my experience.

Comment: Sure with MS Server , but there is no BIT type in the standard, BOOLEAN maybe -- but that requires true and false not 0 and 1

Comment: @Hogan TIL that `BIT` is not in the SQL standard but only SQL Server. I thank you for the education. I'll wait for the OP to chime in that he's actually using SQL Server, which I 100% expect he will. If he was using some other database, I doubt he'd have columns named like they are yes/no decisions but using an `INTEGER` data type.

Comment: Anyway, the essence is that the condition is moved to *before* the join which makes it part of the outer join and again returns all `Persons`. The only thing is, I'd replace "try" by a brief explanation.

Comment: Thank you so much @raven